# Google Maps v3 using markers that move about the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

http://rca2.com/mapping/thispageblinks.htm

http://rca2.com/mapping/doesnotremove.htm

The second example really doesn't do anything without continuously updated xml data.

I'm converting (finally!) my map applications from Google v2 to v3. In v2, the application read in xml data every 5 seconds, cleared markers, then new markers were created and placed on the map. The ability to clear the map overlay using **map.clearOverlays()** no longer exists in v3. The suggested solution is to keep track of the old markers, then remove them. Clearing the markers in a loop prior to creating new markers is easy to do, and works. Except for the fact that the markers blink when replaced more often than not. This is very distracting, and highly undesirable since this did not happen in v2.

I decided that I should compare the new marker data to the old marker data. If the location and icon color stayed the same, both old and new markers are basically ignored. For the sake of clarity, the icon color signifies a status of the vehicle represented by the icon. In this case the application is to track ambulance activity, so green would be available, blue would be en-route, etc.

The code handles the checking of the new and old markers fine, but for some reason, it will never remove the old marker when a marker (unit) moves. I saw suggestions about **setMap()** being asynchronous. I also saw suggestions about the arrays not being **google.maps.Marker** objects. I believe that my code handles each of these issues correctly, however the old markers are still never removed.

I've also made sure that my marker arrays are global variables. I am also using the variable **side_bar_html** to display information about which markers were supposed to be removed, and which markers were supposed to be added. The added markers are being added just fine. I just don't know where to turn next. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
function getMarkers() {

// create a new connection to get our xml data

    var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

// send the get request

    Connect.open("GET", xml_file, false);
    Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    Connect.send(null);

// Place the response in an XML document.

    var xmlDoc = Connect.responseXML;

// obtain the array of markers and loop through it

    var marker_data = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

// hide the info window, otherwise it still stays open where a potentially removed marker used to be

    infowindow.close();

// reset the side_bar and clear the arrays

    side_bar_html = "";
    markerInfo    = [];
    newMarkers    = [];
    remMarkers    = [];
    addMarkers    = [];

// obtain the attributes of each marker

    for (var i = 0; i < marker_data.length; i++) {
        var latData  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("lat");
        var lngData  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("lng");
        var minfo    = marker_data[i].getAttribute("html");
        var name     = marker_data[i].getAttribute("label");
        var icontype = marker_data[i].getAttribute("icontype");
        var unitNum  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("unitNum");
        var llIcon   = latData + lngData + icontype;
        zIndexNum    = zIndexNum + 1;

// create the new marker data needed

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latData), parseFloat(lngData));
        var marker   = {
            position:    myLatLng,
            icon:        gicons[icontype],
            title:       "",
            unitIcon:    unitNum,
            unitLLIData: llIcon,
            zIndex:      zIndexNum
        };

// add a line to the side_bar html

//        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br />';

// add an event listeners on the marker

        addInfoWindow(marker, minfo);

// save the current data for later comparison

        markerInfo.push(minfo);
        newMarkers.push(marker);
    }

// now loop thru the old marker data and compare to the new, to see if we need to remove any old markers

    var refreshIt  = true;
    var removeIt   = true;
    var currNumber = "";
    var currLLIcon = "";
    var lastNumber = "";
    var lastLLIcon = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++) {
        currNumber = newMarkers[i].unitIcon;
        currLLIcon = newMarkers[i].unitLLIData;
        for (var j = 0; j < oldMarkers.length; j++) {
        refreshIt  = true;
            lastNumber = oldMarkers[j].unitIcon;
            lastLLIcon = oldMarkers[j].unitLLIData;
            if (lastNumber == currNumber) {
                if (currLLIcon == lastLLIcon) {
                    refreshIt = false;
                } else {
                    refreshIt = true;
                    remMarkers.push(oldMarkers[j]);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

// if we need to refresh a marker, add it to our new array here

        if (refreshIt == true) {
            addMarkers.push(newMarkers[i]);
        }
    }

// then loop thru and see if any units are no longer on the map

    for (var j = 0; j < oldMarkers.length; j++) {
        removeIt   = true;
        lastNumber = oldMarkers[j].unitIcon;
        for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++) {
            currNumber = newMarkers[i].unitIcon;
            if (lastNumber == currNumber) {
                removeIt = false;
                break;
            }
        }

// if we need to refresh a marker, add it to our new array here

        if (removeIt == true) {
            remMarkers.push(oldMarkers[j]);
        }
    }

// now loop thru the old markers and remove them

    for (var i = 0; i < remMarkers.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(remMarkers[i]);
        marker.setMap(null);
        side_bar_html += 'removing ' + remMarkers[i].unitIcon + '<br />';
    }

// then loop thru the new markers and add them

    for (var i = 0; i < addMarkers.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(addMarkers[i]);
        marker.setMap(map);
        side_bar_html += 'adding ' + addMarkers[i].unitIcon + '<br />';
    }

// and last save the old markers array into oldMarkers

    oldMarkers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++) {
        oldMarkers.push(newMarkers[i]);
    }

// put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div, then sleep

    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    setTimeout('getMarkers()', 5000);
}
```

For context purposes, here is the code that does clear the old markers, but many (not all) or the markers blink when refreshed, even if they don't in fact move loaction.

```
    function getMarkers() {

// create a new connection to get our xml data

    var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

// send the get request

    Connect.open("GET", xml_file, false);
    Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    Connect.send(null);

// Place the response in an XML document.

    var xmlDoc = Connect.responseXML;

// obtain the array of markers and loop through it

    var marker_data = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

// hide the info window, otherwise it still stays open where the removed marker used to be

    infowindow.close();

// now remove the old markers

   for (var i = 0; i < oldMarkers.length; i++) {
        oldMarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }

    oldMarkers.length = 0;

// reset the side_bar and clear the arrays

    side_bar_html = "";
    markerInfo    = [];
    newMarkers    = [];

// obtain the attributes of each marker

    for (var i = 0; i < marker_data.length; i++) {
        var latData  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("lat");
        var lngData  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("lng");
        var minfo    = marker_data[i].getAttribute("html");
        var name     = marker_data[i].getAttribute("label");
        var icontype = marker_data[i].getAttribute("icontype");
        var unitNum  = marker_data[i].getAttribute("unitNum");
        zIndexNum    = zIndexNum + 1;

// create the new marker data needed

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latData), parseFloat(lngData));
        var marker   = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:    myLatLng,
            icon:        gicons[icontype],
            title:       "",
            unitIcon:    unitNum,
            zIndex:      zIndexNum
        });

// add a line to the side_bar html

        side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br />';

// add an event listeners on the marker

        addInfoWindow(marker, minfo);

// save the current data for later comparison

        markerInfo.push(minfo);
        newMarkers.push(marker);
        oldMarkers.push(marker);
    }

// now add the new markers

   for (var i = 0; i < newMarkers.length; i++) {
        newMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }

// put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div, then sleep

    document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;

    setTimeout('getMarkers()', 5000);
}
```

Comment: You are doing what I think you should be doing. In order to remove markers from a map you must store them in an array to be removed at a later time.  I think you need to step through your logic as something is incorrect there if it is not removing them.

Comment: I've updated the code in the two links at the top of my question to pare them down to as small as possible, yet still display the problem. I've tried using the array to clear the marker, using 'splice' and just setting a variable from the array. It never works correctly when trying to clear the marker. I've even swapped the arrays. Setting the marker ALWAYS works. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Again,I think you have a looping/logic issue.  Have you stepped through your code? Because if it is hitting this. : marker.setMap(null);  You should be removing a marker.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the solution. The process was reading in new xml data which was compared to the saved xml data, to determine if a marker needed to be moved or displayed in a different color on the map.

When I created a new marker object, I did not set the map: property, because I needed to compare the lat/lon/color of the new object to the old before I determined whether a marker needed to be moved. The problem was the map: property not being set. I save the marker data without the map: property set into the new marker array, then copied the new marker array into old marker array to do the next comparison. I should have copied the old marker object into the new marker array! The old marker object HAD the map: property set, and that allowed the Google mapping code to know which marker I wanted to remove.

Sorry for the stupid mistake, but I'm pretty new to Javascript.

Rich